# Difference between "activities" and "techniques"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between "activities" and "techniques" in teaching methodology?

Comment: This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information. See the FAQ for guidance on how to improve it.

Comment: thanh, this seems more like a question about teaching methodology than about the English language.

Comment: Yes, he didn't read the FAQ. @JeffSahol

Comment: Given that his name is Vietnamese (or Cambodian) it could easily be that he is genuinely not clear how an activity and a technique in a classroom differ.

Comment: Given that the definitions for [activity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/activity) and [technique](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/technique) are very different, what confusion do you have about them, thanh tran?

Comment: He is asking specifically about teaching. In that case, a particular methodology, such as CLS or PPP, will affect the techniques used in the design of activities. I have seen native speakers get confused over where the boundaries lie.

Answer (score 1):

Activities are things the students do that involve interaction. A game is an activity, but completing individual excercises is not.

Techniques are approaches the teacher uses to teach the students. Using fingers to indicate which word in a sentence is wrong is a technique.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I've put a question here. It took me a lot of time to understand the website regulations. Maybe my question is not clear. I can understand what a technique is and what an activity is. The problem is that I searched google and found no expertise source about the difference. Would you mind providing me with such sources?

Comment: I wouldn't mind at all, but I am not sure what you are asking for. What sort of expert source are you looking for?